# How to add new element into Array of object data through mapping in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  const measurementData = {
    id: 301,
    name: "Topwear",
    measurements: [
      { id: 1, name: "neck" },
      { id: 2, name: "shoulder" }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App mt-5">
      <h1>Update Measurement Data</h1>
      {measurementData.measurements?.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex">
              <label className="col-form-label">{data.name}</label>
              <input type="number" name={data.name} className="form-control"/>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically, I'm mapping through the object.
I just want to add new property called value and save the value that we get from the input field(value: 20) in the end of measurements array of object in measurementData.

// example: the object should be like this after enter values in input field

```
  {
      id: 301,
      name: "Topwear",
      measurements: [
        { id: 1, name: "neck", value: 20},
        { id: 2, name: "shoulder", value: 40 }
      ]
  }
```

[Some UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRj79.png)

Comment: You have a extra `measurements` in `data.measurements.name` when mapping

Comment: sorry about that, i'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a state for the `measurements`. This allows React to re-render the UI when the user types something in the inputs. I moved the `measurementData` code outside the component, if this is dynamic you can simply place it back.

When mapping over the `measurements` to render them we provide the inputs with a `value` prop and pass the current value for that measurement. If there is no value yet we default to `0`.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const measurementData = {
  id: 301,
  name: "Topwear",
  measurements: [
    { id: 1, name: "neck" },
    { id: 2, name: "shoulder" },
  ],
};

export default function App() {
  // create the state
  const [measurements, setMeasurements] = useState(
    measurementData.measurements
  );

  // create the onChange handler
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    setMeasurements((prevState) => {
      // map over the prev measurements
      return prevState.map((measurement) => {
        // if the name is not the same just return the measurement
        if (measurement.name !== name) return measurement;
        // else return a new object with the prev measurement and the new value
        return {
          ...measurement,
          value: value,
        };
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App mt-5">
      <h1>Update Measurement Data</h1>
      {measurements.map((measurement) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex">
            <label className="col-form-label">{measurement.name}</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name={measurement.name}
              value={measurement.value ?? 0}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```